# Passing Multiple Dataset to View [MVC]

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, dataset

I am new to MVC, I referred this link (https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-Send-DataSet-DataTable-from-Controller-to-View-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx) and passing data from Controller, but my project contains multiples Tables and I need to pass the data from Model->Controller->View.
I am facing error while doing this. Kindly check and provide the solution for my issue.

**Error While running the Application**

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MyClassModel.Models.MyClass', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyClassModel.Models.MyClass]'.
```

**<--Model--> (Data Representation)**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyClassModel.Models
{
    public class Myclass
    {
        public List<int> Colors_ID { get; set; }
        public List<string> ColorsInfo { get; set; }
        public List<int> Completexity_code { get; set; }
        public List<string> Completexity_name { get; set; }
        public List<int> DeptCompletexity_code { get; set; }
        public List<string> DeptCompletexity_name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**<--Model--> (Business Logics)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MyClassModel.Models
{
    public class MyClassBL
    {

        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        public DataSet details()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ItrackDropdown", con);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds);
            }
            return ds;

        }
    }
}
```

**<--Controller-->**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MyClassModel.Models;
using System.Data;


namespace MyClassModel.Controllers
{
    public class Home : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {


        MyClass newobj=new MyClass();
        MyClassBL obj = new MyClassBL();
        newobj.Colors_ID= obj.details().Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>("Colors_ID")).ToList();
        newobj.ColorsInfo = obj.details().Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("ColorsInfo")).ToList();
        newobj.Completexity_code = obj.details().Tables[1].AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>("Complexity_code")).ToList();
        newobj.Completexity_name = obj.details().Tables[1].AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Complexity_name")).ToList();
        newobj.DeptCompletexity_code = obj.details().Tables[2].AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>("Complexity_code")).ToList();
        newobj.DeptCompletexity_name = obj.details().Tables[2].AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Complexity_name")).ToList();
        return View(newobj);
        }

    }
}
```

**<--View-->**

```
@model IEnumerable<MyClass.Models.MyClass>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table>
    @foreach (var item1 in @Model.Select(x => x.Colors_ID))
            { 
        <tr>
            <td>
            @item1
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions for your references:
1) Model

a) Model name,

According to the *controller*, the Model name of the first one need update that the following line:

```
public class ItrackDD
```

should be

```
public class MyClass
```

b) Model Design should match the database. it will impact how to fix the error according to #2.

All of the members of the model ItrackDD are  **list**, are you sure?

2) The error message should come from:
In the *controller*, it returned the newobj of type Myclass as in the following code line, which would be passed to the *view*

```
return View(newobj);
```

but in the *view*, it expect a dictionary as in this line:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyClass.Models.MyClass>
```

Comment: 1
a) Now I corrected the class name as Myclass. Actually I changed the code for posting in stack overflow question purpose. 

B. I am not using entity framwork. I think this is not needed. Yes all members in model class are list.

2. Yes, but I am returning list collection objects of class right?

Correct me if I am wrong.

Main reason I need to know why the error is coming.